# reset value using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i want to reset(to old) the values of multiple text boxes when i click on check box. please help

Comment: more information please, and code appreciated

Comment: wich value do you want to change? the value off the clicked input element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean restore the original values of the textboxes? If so, here is the required code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RestoreValues() {
   var arrInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
       var oCurInput = arrInputs[i];
       if (oCurInput.type == "text")
           oCurInput.value = oCurInput.defaultValue;
   }
}
</script>
```

To restore the values just call the function, for example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="RestoreValues();">Restore</button>
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/Nakjv/2/

Edit: using `defaultValue` save lots of code. :)

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript you can restore a default value of an input field like this:

```
var myinput = document.getElementById("myinput");
myinput.value = myinput.defaultValue;
```

HTH

Comment: Forgot about `defaultValue`! :)

Comment: @Joe yes there is and it's even cross browser. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533718(VS.85).aspx and https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL:Property:defaultValue

Comment: @Shadow\ Wizard - sweet. that is handy!

Comment: @Joe yes indeed! BTW using `@` you have to *omit* any spaces so if using the full name it's @ShadowWizard but first three letters are enough so @Sha will work as well. :)